# In C++, why does the main function use 'char *argv[]'?

Tags: c++, language-design

I was wondering why C++ uses the following function prototype for the `main()` function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

instead of something like:

```
int main(std::vector<std::string> argv);
```

What's the reasoning behind using the first? Why not just go with the (much more modern) version using vectors and strings? Is it for backwards compatibility, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Pretty much backwards compatibility, with the platforms which are used to calling a function with a signature of the first.

Comment: Thats legacy. It's inherited directly from C, and it would break binary compatibility to change the prototype of main in the way you suggest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A similar question has been [asked on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072600/why-main-in-c-is-not-overloaded-to-use-stdstring).

In [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12073069/572), [Nicol Bolas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/734069/nicol-bolas) points out that it isn't in the standard because it has to be proposed and voted on. In the way that C++ works, people write proposals for changes, which are voted on. However, he points out that it's a convenience function and doesn't add that much value over the current methods.

In [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12072827/572), [iammilind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/514235/iammilind) suggests that it's against C++'s philosophy. This would add a dependency to the `<string>` and `<vector>` libraries. The current implementation uses built-in and independent types, which doesn't force the library on people. In addition, if a system didn't implement the library, then they would be unable to start the application.

Other answers are also provided, but the two mentioned above are the highest scoring.

Comment: The kind of answer I was expecting. Clears it up, thanks.